# Why does Harry Potter 6 look like it does?

Tags: film-techniques, harry-potter, cinematography, the-half-blood-prince

In a recent Collider podcast the hosts were discussing O Brother Where Art Thou?, and mentioned the cinematographer using (I think), a "digital intermediary" which made the sepia tones.   It was then mentioned that the same method gave HP6 its look, and inferred that this caused consternation on the part of the studio.

Can someone explain the filming technique and how it was received by Warner Bros?

Comment: What do you mean by, "How it was received by Warner Bros.?" I'd say they received it quite well because they let the film out with this type of cinematography and it performed admirably at the box office.

Comment: The podcast made mention that it upset the studio.